# Получение массива Ajax

Tags: ajax, php

Вопрос состоит собственно в следующем : Возможно ли Ajaxом получит не строку, а массив данных ?

```
$.post('some.php',function(resp)
{

})
```

Чтоб в resp пришел массив или объект =)

Comment: Без доп операций - нельзя, вообще для этих целей обычно используется JSON. Т.е. сервер отвечает примерно так: 

      echo json_encode($data);

Теперь осталось выполнить evalJSON на клиенте и получить готовые данные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@AlexWindHope](/users/3545/alexwindhope)](/users/3545/alexwindhope), это вы зря (хотя про серверную часть - верно)

мануал: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

И пример из него:

```
$.post("test.php", { "func": "getNameAndTime" },
 function(data){
   console.log(data.name); // John
   console.log(data.time); //  2pm
 }, "json");
```

Comment: Тонко намекну - "json" в конце **делает именно evalJSON**

Т.е. если быть более точным то в jquery коде написано примерно следующее:

      // ......... code .........
      if(callback !== undefined&&callback.constructor === Function){
      if(request.readyState == 4) {
               var data;
               if(dataType == 'json') {
                   data = evalJSON(request.responseText);     
               }
               // .... code ....
               callback(data) 
           }
      }

Comment: Языки программирования пока не обладают екстросенсорными способностями и указание параметра json в конце метода **$.post** всего-лишь сокращенная записать evalJSON, не более.

Да и комментарий я давал **ОБЩЕГО** характера, дабы люди не думали что jquery творит какуето магию

Comment: Что вы этим хотите сказать? Что я не прав и ваш велосипед красивее встроенной возможности? Я знал все, что вы написали, и все равно не вижу смысла в вашем первом комментарии. Можно было просто сказать, что вы не знали про этот параметр, потому написали то, что написали.

Да, вы правы про evalJSON, да, он вызывается и да, это сокращенная запись, но его использование здесь равноценно такому: `$(document.getElementById('myid'))`. Это отработает как ожидается, но нормальный человек так писать не будет.

Comment: Какбы метки вопроса `ajax php`, что подразумевает что вопрос **общего характера**, в вы везде суете свое jquery

Comment: И для тех кто не умеет читать - повторю, мне не сложно:

"комментарий я давал ОБЩЕГО характера, дабы люди не думали что jquery творит какую-то магию"

То что вы понимаете как это работает - не означает что это понимают другие

Comment: В вопросе еще и кусочек кода явно на jquery. Это не я его сую, это вопрос о нем) 

Вы в комментарии дали неадекватный для jquery(о котором вопрос) ответ "нельзя" и посоветовали юзать функцию, которую там юзать не надо. И человек, запутанный вашим "общим" комментарием, везде писал бы теперь так:
    
    $.post('test.php', function(resp) {
    resp = evalJSON(resp);
    // code
    });

Между прочим, неумение признавать ошибки негативно влияет на душевное здоровье)

Comment: Более того, выяснил, у jquery без плагинов(как и в чистом js, о которо вы, видимо, писали) нет `evalJSON` (у jq есть `$.parseJSON`), потому в комментарии "общего характера" (пардон, понравилось) это тоже надо было бы указать ;) Есть еще аргументы?)

Comment: Причина моего "неадекватного комментария" в метках вопроса. Если бы в метках вопроса было бы jquery - вы были-бы абсолютно правы.

Если кто и ошибся так это автор при выборе меток вопроса.

Comment: По поводу evalJSON - тут вы правы, по стандарту ECMAScript 5 это делается так:

      JSON.parse( text )

В, либе c json.org это делаться точно так-же, evalJSON написал потому-что в основном использовал именно его (prototype.js) и подзабыл, что так эта функция называется только там. 

Я лишь объяснил как это работает, в чем проблема?

А это:

     $.post('test.php', function(resp) {
         resp = evalJSON(resp);
         // code
     });

Написали вы а не я, ниче?

Comment: Трудно объяснять очевидное. 

> Без доп операций - нельзя

Можно.

> Теперь осталось выполнить evalJSON на клиенте и получить готовые данные.

Во-первых, это ровно тот кусок кода(который "написал я, а не вы"). Во-вторых, это не нужно. В-третьих, именно ваш вариант не будет работать без подключения библиотеки (к слову, конфликтующей с jquery). В вопросе явно не чистый js и вы уверенно написали то, что выше, без уточнения синтаксиса. Так обычно пишут, когда уверены в том, что пишут.

В общем, я понял, это бесполезно. В некоторых спорах истина умирает)